# T-SQL Multiplicity many-to-five-or-more/many (0...* -> 5...*)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

If we have something like this in UML:

> > | Championship | ---------------> | Team |
> >
> > Multiplicity:   * -------> 5...*

Each championship has 5 or more teams, how can we control this 'five or more teams' in T-SQL?

Since we have a relationship many to many, we will have intermediate table ( example: tbl_champ_team) with ids from both sides. But how to control that each championship should have 5 or more teams?

Some CHECK when create table? some trigger?

Comment: When do you want this constraint enforced?  If you can't add a team to a championship because there aren't already five teams present then you have a bit of a challenge.  Triggers could help, e.g. to ensure that the number of teams being added by a single statement is >= 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer is that no you can't do that via a check constraint.  Yes, you could apply a trigger to the intersecting table that would make make sure the rowcount of inserted is 5 or more, although I would strongly argue against that.

It seems to me that what you're after is the implementation of a business rule, not a data rule, and if so then this validation should be done there.

Comment: @user1907954 - To add to Ralph's answer, it is often useful to implement business rules in stored procedures such that violations are reported.  For example, add an `IsValid` column to `GetAllChampionships()` that indicates whether or not all of the business rules have been met for each row.  The application can use the bit to display the championship in red, disable some functions, ... .  I find it much better than making a user try to find the one painful path that will let them navigate through all of the rules to achieve their end without any intermediate violations.

Comment: @Ralph Shillington - i have a business rule saying "A championship has to have at least 5 Teams, and a team can enroll in more than one championship". What is this data rule? You mean implementation level? "...and if so then this validation should be done there", you mean with trigger right? 

My main question is: If i have this model in UML, how can i implement this to be coherent with the model?

Comment: Others may disagree, but I take Data rules to be immutable, unbreakable.  For example, a Birthdate must be of type DateTime.  That's a data rule, if you say it must not be null, that's another data rule.  No amount of managerial override will change that rule.

A Championship has at least 5 teams, is a great example of something that is likely to be reconfigured for a different league, or overridden at some point in time, because there's an odd number of teams or some such thing.  Businesses need to be able to adapt to those possibilities, which is why business rules somewhat more flexible.

Answer (score 0):

One way (It is a bit convoluted) is to have a separate table just to implement this constraint. It would have Championship PK column, with TeamA, TeamB, TeamC, TeamD, and TeamE as non-nullable FKs, and another table that has all teams in it as you envision in your question. Add 5 FK constraints between {Championship and TeamA} to the many to many table, and {Championship, TeamB} to the same table, etc.

Then you can't create a championship without populating the five team attributes.  This by itself would still not be 100% accurate, as it would allow you to enter a championship with two or more of the teams as the same team, which I imagine you would not want...  I can't come up with a way to eliminate that possibility.